# angular material drag&drop calls callback after css transition end

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, drag-and-drop

I have implemented list of elements which can be drag and dropped via angular material drag and drop feature
like in tutorial https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview

I've implemented function drop(event) however in my case i need not just move elements in angular model. I need to send request to server and when response from server will come update it. So my function is not changing anything, it creates request to server.

Problem here is that because angular model is not changed at drop function there is an element "jumping" occurs: after element drop element returns to the position where it was and when response from server comes and model is updated element move to new position. For user it's very painful to see that

I want to hide somehow from user that some work is going in the background.

1. Idea to have duplicated list which is for user and another one for server and update them (user list at the moment of drop and server list at the moment of response) I left as last decision because it's hard to maintain.

I'm trying to resolve it with css animations. As you can see in drag&drop example it uses

```
.cdk-drag-animating {
  transition: transform 250ms cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1);
}
```

"transition: transform" to show smooth animation when user drops element. So i want to show user animation about 0.5s. This time should be enough for response from server and when animation is finished model is already updated.

What i'm seeing is that

```
(cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
```

drop function is called AFTER transition is ended. So even if I do transform 2000ms drop function will be called after transition end, so after 2s. Is it expected? I thought function should be called after mouse release.

Do you have any thoughts for initial problem(hide model update) and for this css animation transition problem in particular?

Update:
I've created example of my problem
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3nhsxx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-drag-drop-disabled-sorting-example.css,src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-drag-drop-disabled-sorting-example.ts

Answer (score 0):

> drop function is called AFTER transition is ended. So even if I do transform 2000ms drop function will be called after transition end, so after 2s. Is it expected? I thought function should be called after mouse release.

Yes, it is expected. The reason for this has a technically background. `cdkDrag` create a deep copy of the dragged element and set the position of the other items with position fixed. If the drag finished (mouse up) the animation starts and first when the animation is finished Angular will "resort" the items for a good transitions. Otherwise the elements will "jump" back to start order and then to new order.

You can use `cdkDragReleased` which fires directly **before** the animation ends. I think this is what you want. [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3nhsxx-twqc4f?file=src/app/cdk-drag-drop-disabled-sorting-example.ts) is updated.

Additional informations (container, index, item) can found in `cdkDragExited` and `cdkDragEntered` as example. More in the official [docs](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api#CdkDrag).

**Demo:**

```
<div cdkDropListGroup>
  <div class="example-container">
    <h2>Available items</h2>

    <div
      cdkDropList
      id="test"
      [cdkDropListData]="items"
      class="example-list"
      cdkDropListSortingDisabled
      (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
>
      <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of items" (cdkDragEntered)="cdkDropListEntered($event)"
      (cdkDragExited)="cdkDropListExited($event)" (cdkDragReleased)="dragEnd($event)" cdkDrag>{{item}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="example-container">
    <h2>Shopping basket</h2>

    <div
    id="super"
      cdkDropList
      [cdkDropListData]="basket"
      class="example-list"
      (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
      >
      <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of basket" (cdkDragEntered)="cdkDropListEntered($event)"
      (cdkDragExited)="cdkDropListExited($event)" (cdkDragReleased)="dragEnd($event)" cdkDrag>{{item}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*Code*

```
dragEnd(event: any) {
    console.log('End', event);
  }

  cdkDropListEntered(event: any) {
    console.log(event);
  }

  cdkDropListExited(event: any) {
    console.log(event);
  }
```

Comment: sorry i noticed your answer only today. Yes cdkDragReleased exactly what i needed, but unfortunately it doesn't have enough info for request. I tried to get additional info with another functions like cdkDragExited like you proposed but it look like it's not possible to find index of item which is dragged. Moreover i found out that if response from server comes earlier than animation transition finished there is angular errors in console. Looks like angular can't correctly process situation when item, which is dragged, changed his position in model during animation transition